# react material-table's search filter does not work on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, render, material-ui

The Search works fine here :

```
 <MaterialTable
          columns={[
            { title: 'Name', field: 'firstname', type: 'string' }
          ]}
/>
```

However Search filter does not work for the below code:

```
<MaterialTable
          columns={[
             { title: 'Name',
               render: rowData =>{ 
                       return(<Link to = {`/${rowData.firstname}`}> 
                       {rowData.firstname} 
                       </Link>)
               },
               type: 'html'
              }
            ]}
/>
```

Comment: I just noticed you never actually closed the square bracket opened at 
columns={[ .please try closing the tag and retry.

Comment: @SiavashRostami Sorry that was a typo.. I have updated the code now. Still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 This is the correct way to search on render. We need to add field to it.

 <MaterialTable
              columns={[
                 { title: 'Name',
                   field: 'location_name',
                   render: rowData =>{ 
                           return(<Link to = {`/${rowData.firstname}`}> 
                           {rowData.firstname} 
                           </Link>)
                   },
                   type: 'html'
                  }
                ]}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like user10665299 told you, need to add the `field`.. You can delete the `type` attribute, is not neccesary